# Scala "cursor.asInstanceOf[::[A]].tl = newElem" what does it mean

Tags: scala, casting, listbuffer

I am looking at the source code for Scala's mutable ListBuffer here
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L158

and I ran into this cast on line 158.  I have been unable to figure out what `.asInstanceOf[::[A]]` means.  `::` is not a bounds notation that I could find in the documentation.  But, it is a method for a List.  Can anyone explain what this cast is doing?

Answer (score 1):

`::` is a list constructor that is composed of head and tail (as opposed to `Nil` which has neither). In other words it's a kind of list that guarantees that it contains at least one element (head).

You can find its definition in `List.scala`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L439

So what this cast does is that it turns the `cursor` typed as `List[A]` into more specific `::[A]`, that allows accessing its `tl` variable, representing list tail. Which is necessary for efficient `update` operation.